# How to configure MFP server log level?

Tags: logging, mobile, websphere-liberty, server.xml, mfp

I am hitting some issue in my mobile app, but I didnt see any error from messages.log. I suspect my log level in my MFP server is not accessible enough, thus I would like to change the log level to `INFO` so that I can see more thing.

I am referring to this website, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5
However,I am still not sure how to configure it in my `server.xml`, for example `consoleLogLevel`, I put `<consoleLogLevel>INFO</consoleLogLevel>` in my `server.xml`, but my messageslog doesn't change anything.

Kindly advise on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Mobile First Platform KnowledgeCenter topic https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/r_logging_and_monitoring_mechanisms.html
MobileFirst logger packages all begin with com.ibm.mfp and Application Center logs begin with com.ibm.puremeap.
Consider enabling trace for those class packages and look at trace.log.
In server.xml, specify `<logging traceSpecification="com.ibm.mfp.*=<level>:com.ibm.puremeap.*=<level>"/>` where level can be **detail**, **fine**, **finer**, **finest**, **all**.  Start with **detail** level and see if that captures what you need, if not, try increasing the log levels.